# View Ruler icon and Split Window icon in Office 2013. Where did they go?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Office 2010 and previous versions of Word, there was a non-distinct icon below the equally non-distinct "split window" icon. It had a tool-tip (View Ruler). These icons sat smack-dab on top of the vertical scroll bar. Where are they in Word 2013? These were staples for me! The icon "toggled" the ruler off and on. Ditto the Split Screen feature. You could click or drag the icon to "split" the window.

Answer (score 1):

There's options under the "View" tab, Show->Ruler and Window->Split that seem to take care of these features. Not sure if Microsoft opted to remove the scrollbar icons, maybe because most people weren't aware of them.